# Passing dynamic allocating object into boost::any constructor

Tags: c++, boost, any

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/any.hpp>

class Str
{
public:
  // default constructor
  Str() : str_{"Hello, World!"} { std::cout << "A::A()" << this << std::endl;  }

  // copy constructor
  Str(const Str& that) : str_(that.str_) { std::cout << "A::A(const A&)" << this << std::endl; }
  Str(Str& that) : str_(that.str_) { std::cout << "A::A(A&)" << this << std::endl; }

  // move constructor
  Str(const Str&& that) : str_(std::move(that.str_)) { std::cout << "A::A(const A&&)" << this << std::endl; }
  Str(Str&& that) : str_(std::move(that.str_)) { std::cout << "A::A(A&&)" << this << std::endl; }
  // destructor
  ~Str() { std::cout << "~A::A()" << this << std::endl; }

  // str print method
  void print() const { std::cout << str_ << '\n'; }

private:
  std::string str_;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  auto* str = new Str;
  boost::any a(*str);
  if (a.empty()) {
    std::cout << "empty\n";
  } else {
    std::cout << "not empty\n";
  }
  auto s = boost::any_cast<Str>(&a);
  std::cout << s << std::endl;
  std::cout << a.empty() << std::endl;
  delete str;
  return 0;
}
```

This simple program have output:

```
A::A()0x24f5c20
not empty
0
0
~A::A()0x24f5c20
```

And so, to understand it right, the correct program output need to be:

```
A::A()0x24f5c20
A::A(const A&)some address // copy str before passing into any constructor
not empty 
some address 
0 
~A::A()some address //~any() call ~A()some address
~A::A()0x24f5c20
```

It looks like don't understand what is going on.
That was compiled with g++ version 5.4.0. 
People! What is wrong with me? =)

Comment: I can't reproduce that. Which version of Boost are you using?

Comment: I'm using 1.62 version of boost.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume you are running an old version of the program or not correctly rebuilding it. (I've tested with boost 1.62 as well as 1.64. Using Gcc 5.4 and Clang.)

The program has the intended effect and does not invoke any kind of undefined behaviour.

Note however, that there's no reason to use `new`/`delete` there, and `str` is not used after initializing the `boost::any`, since `boost::any` stores values - never references. You could therefore simply say

```
auto *str = new Str;
boost::any a(*str);
delete str;
```

Or just

```
Str str;
boost::any a(str);
```

Or even

```
boost::any a(Str{}); // beware of "most vexing parse"
```

You can compare things **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ebb508eee78f70f0)**